# Cant publish app with a xcframework that contains pods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcframework

**Context**

I developed a framework that contains the following pods: CryptoSwift, SwiftyRSA and PromiseKit. I distribute it as a xcframework in cocoapods. This is how I generated the xcframework:

```
xcodebuild archive -workspace MySDK.xcworkspace -scheme MySDK -destination="iOS" -archivePath ./ios.xcarchive -derivedDataPath /tmp/iphoneos -sdk iphoneos SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES     
xcodebuild archive -workspace MySDK.xcworkspace -scheme MySDK -destination="iOS Simulator" -archivePath ./iossimulator.xcarchive -derivedDataPath /tmp/iphoneos -sdk iphonesimulator SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework ./ios.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MySDK.framework -framework ./iossimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MySDK.framework -output ./MySDK.xcframework
```

**Problem**

When I validate the app before for distribution in App Store Connect it fails showing the following error messages:

> App Store Connect Operation Error Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file
> 'MySDKTest.app/Frameworks/MySDK.framework/Frameworks/Pods_MySDK.framework/Pods_MySDK'
> is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or
> libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles.
> Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at
> https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on
> the iOS app bundle structure.

> App Store Connect Operation Error Invalid Bundle. The bundle at
> 'MySDKTest.app/Frameworks/MySDK.framework' contains
> disallowed nested bundles.

> App Store Connect Operation Error Invalid Bundle. The bundle at
> 'MySDKTest.app/Frameworks/MySDK.framework' contains
> disallowed file 'Frameworks'.

Comment: Hello, I developed a library exactly like this. But when I try to test the application using the library on the device, I get the following error. How did you solve this problem? dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/CryptoSwift.framework/CryptoSwift
  Referenced from:....5D748-586C-43AC-99C8-4CE86DD1D34F/Trackly.app/Frameworks/InstalibSDKFramework.framework/Frameworks/CryptoSwift.framework/CryptoSwift) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.

Comment: I ended up removing the pods from the project and adding the source code manually.

Comment: :D, Also I added the source manually, I can not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In build setting of your framework change
Always Embed Swift Standard Libaries -> No